# Why isn't my dropdown menu centered with max-width?

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive drop down menu that will center on its smallest size when the width is 100% but wont when its changed to a max width of 100%. I have its parent and its parent's parent's ect set to a max-width of 100% but the max-width property doesn't seem to work like its supposed to.

From my understanding max-width is relative to the parent so if its parent and its parent's parents are set to a max width of 100%, the smallest child that is set to a width of max-width should have same width as the highest parent, which is max width of 100%.

Is there something wrong with my code or am I understanding something wrong? I know I can just solve the problem with width of 100% but I want to understand why the max-width isnt workng

```css
nav {
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

nav li > span, nav  a {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

nav li {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.main-nav {
  position: relative;

}
.sub-nav {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.sub-nav li {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.sub-nav li a {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.main-nav:hover .sub-nav {
  display: block;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 450px){
  nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 2px;
  }
  nav ul {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 5% 0 0;
  }
  .main-title {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 0 15px 15%;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    color: orange;
    font-size: 4em;
  }

}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="main-title">This Is a Test</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="main-nav home-page active">
        <a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav">
        <span> Content 1 </span>
        <ul class="sub-nav">
          <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="main-nav">
        <span> Content 2 </span>
        <ul class="sub-nav">
          <li><a href="page4.html">Page 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="page5.html">Page 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="page6.html">Page 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="main-nav">
        <span> Content 3 </span>
        <ul class="sub-nav">
          <li><a href="page7.html">Page 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="page1.html">Page 8</a></li>
          <li><a href="page1.html">Page 9</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rueczkha/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what `max-width` has to do with it, but simply removing the text alignment results in a centered menu.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 450px) {
    ...
    nav ul {
        /* text-align: right; */
        ...
    }
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/gyL8nmLe/)**

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/gyL8nmLe/1/) I've removed every instance of `max-width`, and nothing seems to change.